# Compiling ocaml can't find module in opam library, Js.ml in js_from_ocaml

Tags: ocaml, js-of-ocaml

## Trying to compile ocaml into javascript.

Some OCaml code I have put in https://gist.github.com/larsr/6b3cd6f62d54d56e3f9a uses the `menhir` parser, and the `js_of_ocaml` library together.   I've installed them with `opam`.

The code comes from http://toss.sourceforge.net/ocaml.html.
It is a lexer and a parser and a main program that calls them.
The goal is to generate a javascript program from the ocaml code and run it from within a web page.

I am able to compile the first Main program using only `menhir` with `make` from the Makefile in the repo, which does

```
ocamlbuild -use-menhir -menhir "menhir --external-tokens Lexer" Main.native
```

and I can compile a program that only uses `js_of_ocaml`, with `make Formula.js`, which does

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -package js_of_ocaml -package js_of_ocaml.syntax \
      -syntax camlp4o -linkpkg -o Formula.byte Formula.ml
js_of_ocaml Formula.byte
```

My problem is that now I'm unable to get `ocamlfind` to build `JsClient.js`, with

```
make JsClient.js
```

so I can't produce javascript code for 'JsClient.ml'.  The error I get is that the compiler can't find the module `Js` which is used by `JsClient`.  The code seems to be in the opam library in my home-dir, but I can't get the right arguments to `ocamlfind` to use it.

How do I compile the `JsClient.ml` into `JsClient.js`?

Comment: I ended up writing a new Makefile, perhaps it is useful for someone to take a look at. https://gist.github.com/larsr/6b3cd6f62d54d56e3f9a#file-makefile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule that you use to compile the `JsClient.ml` file is not good.

```
JsClient.byte:
    ocamlbuild -use-menhir -menhir "menhir --external-tokens Lexer"
```

As you said, this file use the module `Js` so you need to compile with the same way than the file `Formula.ml` :

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -package js_of_ocaml -package js_of_ocaml.syntax \
      -syntax camlp4o -linkpkg -o JsClient.byte JsClient.ml
js_of_ocaml JSClient.byte
```